# call file in localhost

Tags: php, xml, localhost, relative-path

I have a file test.php with php generated xml code in my subdomain. Now I would like to get the data with the php function xml_parse on my homepage. This is the code I use: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_xml_parse.asp

If I open the file http://www.website.com/test.php I get the right code, but how can I do that on localhost with relative paths? I cannot use ./subdomain.com/test.php because that doesn't generate the php code in the subdomain. How can I call the file so that it parse the php. I can do it with http://localhost/subdomain.com/test.php but then I must always change it when I upload the file to the live website.

Thanks for your help, and sorry for my English;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
    $url = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$url = preg_replace("/[^\/]+$/","test.php",$url);
```

That takes the current file that's running and replaced the filename with test.php, automatically adapting to it's location.